# How to automatically change the Quality Gate?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

We are using Jenkins as our CI server, and Sonarqube for code analysis.

Currently we are using SonarQube 4.5.7 and we want to upgrade to version 6.5. We have several quality gates, and we can't find an **automatic** way to assign the quality gate to the project.

In previous version we used the `sonar.QualityGate` property, but this property is now deprecated.

How can we let Jenkins setup the quality gate **before** it starts the analysis?

Comment: the field is still working :D but you could use the API

Comment: do you have branchbased analysis running? else you can simply set the profile once within the admin panel of the project and it will stick to it.-> if you use like sonar4stash as a bitbucket plugin, this can also set your profiles and gates according of the target branch

Comment: @SimonSchrottner I just try to use it add a non exist quality gate and it ignore it. 

we run sonar for every branch this is the reason why we need to add the gate dynamically , do you have any api usage example , I can't make it work ...

Comment: https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api -> you can find all the necessary informations there normally...

Comment: Why do you have to set the quality gate automatically? Do you change it regularly? Or do you drop your project before each analysis?

Comment: @slartidan I have several quality gates , and since we scan each branch I need to have the ability to update it before the scan.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sonar.branch` property to run branch the analysis. I guess (not tested) that the main project's quality gate will apply.

If that is not an option for whatever reason, use `curl` to provision the project and to set the quality gate:

```
curl -s -u admin:admin -XPOST "localhost:9000/api/projects/create?project=b&name=bla"  | python -m json.tool
curl -s -u admin:admin -XPOST "localhost:9000/api/qualitygates/select?projectKey=b&gateId=1"  | python -m json.tool
```